# Select rows where field in joining table is same in every row

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE parents (
    id int primary key
);

CREATE TABLE children (
    parent_id int,  --id from parents
    day int,
    status bool,
}

INSERT INTO parents (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO children (parent_id, day, status) VALUES (1, 1, TRUE);
INSERT INTO children (parent_id, day, status) VALUES (1, 2, TRUE);

INSERT INTO parents (id) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO children (parent_id, day, status) VALUES (2, 1, TRUE);
INSERT INTO children (parent_id, day, status) VALUES (2, 2, FALSE);

INSERT INTO parents (id) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO children (parent_id, day, status) VALUES (3, 1, TRUE); 

INSERT INTO parents (id) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO children (parent_id, day, status) VALUES (4, 1, FALSE);

INSERT INTO parents (id) VALUES (5);
```

I need a query that will return:

```
Parents
+------------+
|    id      |
+------------+
|     1      |
|     3      |
+------------+
```

where `id` is parents id. The resulting table only contains the parents that always(any day) `true`. Note that parents without children should be excluded.

My attempt:

```
SELECT id
FROM parents p
INNER JOIN children c ON c.parent_id=p.id
WHERE c.status = TRUE
GROUP BY id
```

But it will also give parent with `id=2`.

Another attempt:

```
SELECT id
FROM parents p
LEFT OUTER JOIN children c ON c.parent_id=p.id AND c.status=FALSE
WHERE c.status IS NULL
GROUP BY id
```

But this approach will also include parent with `id=5`, which must be excluded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to join to parents.

```
SELECT parent_id
FROM children
GROUP BY parent_id
HAVING MIN(Status) = 'TRUE'
   AND MAX(Status) = 'TRUE'
```

No other Status besides TRUE.

Comment: In the event that `status` could be `NULL`, you can add `AND COUNT(*) = COUNT(status)`.

Comment: Thanks! This is the only answer that gave the correct answer in all scenarios, and it is also the most straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id FROM parent P 
WHERE (P.id) IN
(SELECT c.parent_id FROM children c WHERE c.status = TRUE)
```

This will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This might also work

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id
  FROM parents p
 WHERE p.id IN ( 
                 SELECT c.parent_id
                   FROM children c
                  WHERE c.status = TRUE
                    AND c.parent_id = p.id 
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `bit_add`:

```
select a.id
from parents a
join children b on a.id = b.parent_id
group by a.id
having bit_and(b.status);
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d29dd/2)